# Bash Script to open Terminal, execute script in sudo (no password) and remain open?

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I want to create a bash script to open a terminal, execute a command as sudo (without entering password) and not have the terminal close after?

Requirements:
I am trying to launch xmrig which is located in /home/restless/xmrig-6.17.0
I need to execute it with sudo privilege's but don't want to type the password in each time.
I then plan to hook the script into a cron job to start at reboot then schedule regular reboots.

Please keep it as simple as possible as I am what's known as a super noob lol. This is one of my first "advanced" (in my opinion) ubuntu projects.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this? If you plan to run your script with cron you can do that as root so no need to worry about entering a password except while you develop it and run it manually. Don’t put sudo in your script. Run the script as sudo. You might want to check out systemd units. They provide an alternative to cron that in my experience is less problematic. If you want to see the output of your script you can always redirect it to a text file with something like `sh myscript.txt >> my log.txt`

Comment: Unfortunately no I have not made any progress on the bash script itself. I cant figure out how to run the program in terminal and not close said terminal after.

Comment: Normal terminal behaviour is to return to a command prompt after the script ends. Are you sure your script doesn’t have something in it that closes the window or perhaps an error closes it. Have you tried redirecting the terminal output to a file as I suggested above

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-to-redirect-and-append-both-standard-output-and-standard-error-to-a-file-wit